Solving boundary value problem with complete integrals
I am trying to solve the following terminal value problem on $[0,T]\times [0,+\infty)$:
\begin{align*}
\nonumber P_t(t,d)&+P_d(t,d)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{d+(T-t)+1}\\
        &+(P_d(t,d)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{d+(T-t)+1}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(d+(T-t)+1)^2})^2=0.
\end{align*}
The terminal condition is $P(T,d)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(d+1)-\frac{d}{2(d+1)}$.
This non-linear first order equation can be viewed as a Hamilton-Jacobi equation, which does not admit classical solutions in general. I recently got to know that it is possible to construct a complete integral for the above equation.
My question is: Given a complete integral to the above equation, is it possible to construct a solution such that the boundary condition is satisfied? If the answer is negative, what other methods are applicable to produce classical solutions to the above terminal value problem?

Yes, it's possible in principle. The procedure is explained here and here.
